# boost async_read_some reads wrong buffer

Tags: c++, memory-management, asynchronous, boost-asio

am trying to receive to a `queue->buffer` where `queue->buffer` is `char * buffer = new char[1024]`

```
void AsyncConnection::BeginReceive(){

    m_socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(&queue->GetBuffer()[queue->GetOffset()], queue->GetBufferLength() - queue->GetOffset()), boost::bind(&AsyncConnection::EndReceive, shared_from_this(),
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

and am converting the bytes array to hex using this method :-

```
#include <iomanip>
void output_hex(std::ostream& out, char* buf, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        out << std::noshowbase
        << std::hex
        << std::setfill('0')
        << std::setw(2)
        << static_cast<int> (buf[i])
        << " ";
    out << std::dec << std::endl;
}
```

the output looks like this :-

```
17 ffffff84 04 65 ffffff83 45 fffffff3 ffffffe2 ffffffdf 0f 33 ffffffa5 14 fffff
fcb 75 6f 5f ffffff89 ffffffb0 22 27 fffffffe ffffffeb fffffff2 ffffffef ffffffe
8 53 40 ffffffbe 18 ffffffa6 ffffff84 67 53 33 ffffffd6 ffffffa6 16 ffffff81 fff
fffe0 ffffffd9 05 35 ffffffab 16 ffffffc1 7f 6d 59 ffffff87 ffffffba 20
```

which is wrong those `ffffff` is wrong! maybe there is a bad allocation of some sort?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which is wrong those `ffffff` is wrong!

That's because, on your platform, `char` is signed and so the byte values are treated as signed types. Any value with the top bit set (such as the second value, `84`) will be regarded as negative, and the conversion to `int` will set all the new bits to 1 to preserve the negative value. That gives the `ffffff`.

One option is to use `unsigned char` rather than `char` everywhere you're dealing with binary data.

Another option is to convert to `unsigned char` rather than `int` for output.